GitLab Email Error
The GitLab Computer (GC) has a CNAME on CloudFlare routed through their Argo tunnel. There are also two sets of MX records, one for the GC and the other for the $TLD.
The GC has the website routed with NGINX and proxy_pass on a different computer on the same LAN accessible by the larger internet.
I have setup Postfix and have the config info within the gitlab.rb
The command Notify.test_email('cethomme@la', 'Test Email', 'This is a test.').deliver_now within the gitlab-rails console last evening was `check_response': 450 4.7.1 - : Client host rejected: No resolvable MX records for GitLab computer (GC) (DNS response: NOERROR) (Net::SMTPServerBusy)
Today after the network settled, the error is 554 5.7.1 - : Client host rejected: Sender address must match login name for this account type. Identities can be enabled in the account control center. (Net::SMTPFatalError)
Using swaks I can send a test email successfully. swaks --to cethomme@la --server smtpauth --port --auth --auth-user $UserInGitLab --auth-password --tls --from $UserInGitLab 
Email sent within the GC console fails though the system can send email as intended.
The gitlab.rb config has this:
> gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
> gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = 'smtpauth'
> gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = $port
> gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = '$UserInGitLab'
> gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = ' '
> gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "$TLD"
> gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = ' '
> gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
> gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false
> # gitlab_rails['smtp_pool'] = false

Where is the Server Fault?

Via Neil on reddit,
https://www.reddit.com/r/gitlab/comments/1hcp4ht/gitlab_email_error/
the solution was to add gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = ' 'within the gitlab.rb configuration file explicitly stating the origin sending email address.
